# errors deploying an EAR with EJBs 2.1 into JBoss AS5

Tags: ejb, jboss5.x

I'm porting an application with EJBs 2.1 from Weblogic9 to JBoss AS5. I have made some of the changes like adding jboss.xml descriptors to EJBs and fixing application.xml of the EAR, but there are still problems when deploying the EAR. Here is a summary of the the latest error I'm getting when the first EJB is being deployed by JBoss (I will add the full stack trace at the end of the message):

```
14:15:48,124 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vf
sfile:/C:/Marina/Tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/contracts.ear/ state
=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for v
fsfile:/C:/Marina/Tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/contracts.ear/admin
-ejb.jar/



....

Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Failed
  to parse schema for nsURI=, baseURI=null, schemaLocation=http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_2_4.dtd



....

Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: -1:-1 94:3 The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Is this a problem with parsing the jboss_2_4.dtd itself? or is it something worng with my descriptors for the EJB?

When I try to validate the jboss_2_4.dtd in an XML editor it does complain about a syntax error at line 94:1 , which is the beginning of the first  declaration, although it looks fine. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Marina

Full error stack trace:

```
14:15:48,124 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vf
sfile:/C:/Marina/Tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/contracts.ear/ state
=Not Installed mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for v
fsfile:/C:/Marina/Tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/contracts.ear/admin
-ejb.jar/
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentExcept
ion(DeploymentException.java:49)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithO
utput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:362)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithO
utput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:322)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithO
utput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:294)
        at org.jboss.deployment.JBossEjbParsingDeployer.createMetaData(JBossEjbP
arsingDeployer.java:95)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithO
utput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:234)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(Deployer
Wrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(Deployer
sImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFi
rst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(Deployers
Impl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(Deployers
Impl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeploye
rImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter
.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction
.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileActi
on.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(Abstra
ctControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractContr
oller.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(Abstra
ctController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(Abstr
actController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractContro
ller.java:553)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileServ
ice.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(
ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:
461)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Failed
to parse schema for nsURI=, baseURI=null, schemaLocation=http://www.jboss.org/j
2ee/dtd/jboss_2_4.dtd
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBPars
er.java:203)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java
:168)
        at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:189)
        at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:166)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(Sch
emaResolverDeployer.java:137)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(Sch
emaResolverDeployer.java:121)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse
AndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:256)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse
(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:188)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithO
utput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:348)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: Failed to parse schema
for nsURI=, baseURI=null, schemaLocation=http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_2_4
.dtd
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.resolver.AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.resolve(A
bstractMutableSchemaResolver.java:293)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.SundayContentHandler.startE
lement(SundayContentHandler.java:274)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser$DelegatingContentHan
dler.startElement(SaxJBossXBParser.java:401)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.startElement(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unkn
own Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.s
canRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContent
Dispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Un
known Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBPars
er.java:199)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: -1:-1 94:3 The markup i
n the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinderTerminatingErrorHa
ndler.handleError(XsdBinderTerminatingErrorHandler.java:40)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reportDOMFatalError(Unknown
Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XSLoaderImpl.load(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.Util.loadSchema(Util.java:395)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bind(XsdBinder.ja
va:176)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.XsdBinder.bind(XsdBinder.ja
va:147)
        at org.jboss.xb.binding.resolver.AbstractMutableSchemaResolver.resolve(A
bstractMutableSchemaResolver.java:285)
        ... 58 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to see your `jboss.xml` but I really wonder why you're using this very dusty `jboss_2_4.dtd` (the "JBoss 2.4 EJB deploymentDescriptor"). Since you're using JBoss AS 5.1, I'd recommend using the moderner [jboss_5_1.xsd](http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_5_1.xsd) schema instead (see [JBossDTDs](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossDTDs) for reference). Below an empty sample:

```
<jboss xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_5_1.xsd"
 version="3.0">
</jboss>
```

Comment: Pascal, thanks for your answer - for some reason it just showed up in my mailbox... Just like you suggested, I fixed the problem by switching to a newer DTD. Although I used the <!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 4.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_4_0.dtd"> one. The reason I used the old one in the first place was because for some reason (probably old version of xdcolet itself) the jboss.xml generated by xdoclet in my build file had this old DTD.
Thanks!
Marina

Comment: @Marina You're welcome. Feel free to accept this answer then (the green tick below the vote score on the left).